# Using PIL to show image (png) in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Environment:

Python 3.7.2
Mac OS 10.14.3

I am try to find a way to show a image (jpg/png) in the terminal application.

And I found a working solution for jpg image here:

[Display Images in Linux Terminal using Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=f77rKzqBzEA)

With the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def get_ansi_color_code(r, g, b):
    if r == g and g == b:
        if r < 8:
            return 16
        if r > 248:
            return 231
        return round(((r - 8) / 247) * 24) + 232
    return 16 + (36 * round(r / 255 * 5)) + (6 * round(g / 255 * 5)) + round(b / 255 * 5)

def get_color(r, g, b):
    return "\x1b[48;5;{}m \x1b[0m".format(int(get_ansi_color_code(r,g,b)))

def show_image(img_path):
    try:
        img = Image.open(img_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        exit('Image not found.')
    h = 100
    w = int((img.width / img.height) * h)
    img = img.resize((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img_arr = np.asarray(img)

    for x in range(0, h):
        for y in range(0, w):
            pix = img_arr[x][y]
            print(get_color(pix[0], pix[1], pix[2]), sep='', end='')
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_image(sys.argv[1])
```

The problem is when I try to use this code for a png file I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img-viewer.py", line 62, in <module>
    show_image(sys.argv[1])
  File "img-viewer.py", line 40, in show_image
    print(get_color(pix[0], pix[1], pix[2]), sep='', end='')
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

It seems like when processing a jpg file the `pix` is a tuple while with a png file the `pix` is a int value.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Try with some other PNG? The PNG I've tried works with your code.

Comment: I believe you are really using `PIL`. But actually it has been deprecated. You need to first uninstall it and install `pillow`.

Answer (score 2):

Your image may be greyscale, or palettised. Either way there will only be 1 channel, not 3. So change this line

```
img = Image.open(img_path)
```

to

```
img = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
```

so you get the 3 channels you expect and it all works nicely.

---

I noticed that your resizing code tries to keep the same aspect ratio in the resized image, which is all very laudable, but... the pixels on a Terminal are not actually square! If you look at the cursor up close, it is around 2x as tall as it is wide, so I changed the line of resizing code to allow for this:

```
w = int((img.width / img.height) * h) * 2
```

**Keywords**: PIL, Pillow, terminal, console, ANSI, escape sequences, graphics, ASCII art, image, image processing, Python

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the recolored img into seven groups as below,

```
front     |     back        |   color
------------------------------------------
30        |        40       |    black
31        |        41       |    red
32        |        42       |    green
33        |        43       |    yello
34        |        44       |    blue
35        |        45       |    purple
36        |        46       |    violet
37        |        47       |    white
-------------------------------------------
```

And the code,

```
from PIL import Image  
import numpy as np  
import sys
import os

image = Image.open(sys.argv[1])   
img = np.array(image)

x=5 #step
y=5 #step
img1=img[0:img.shape[0]:x,0:img.shape[1]:y]
#img1=img1 // 37 #resize

for i in range(img.shape[0]//x):
    str = "echo "
    for j in range(img.shape[1]//y):
        if img1[i, j] == 0:
            str=str+'\x1b[41;31m  '
        elif img1[i,j]==1:
            str=str+'\x1b[42;31m  '
        elif img1[i,j]==2:
            str=str+'\x1b[43;31m  '
        elif img1[i,j]==3:
            str=str+'\x1b[44;31m  '
        elif img1[i,j]==4:
            str=str+'\x1b[45;31m  '
        elif img1[i,j]==5:
            str=str+'\x1b[46;31m  '
        elif img1[i, j] == 6:
            str = str + '\x1b[47;31m ' 
    str = str + '\x1b[0m'
    os.system(str)
```